# Styled Document for JScrollBar?

Tags: java, swing, document, jtextpane, jscrollbar

I want to customize the output of my scrollbar object. The code below works perfectly for JTextPane, what is the equivalent for JScrollBar?

```
    private JTextPane textPane;

    StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

    SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setForeground(keyWord, Color.RED);
    StyleConstants.setBackground(keyWord, Color.YELLOW);
    StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);
```

Comment: JScrollBar has no document...  it has no text-representation, for which an document would be required...  maybe you subclass JScrollBar and insert your own document in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation [**How to Use Scroll Panes**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html),

> A JScrollPane provides a scrollable view of a component. When screen real estate is limited, use a scroll pane to display a component that is large or one whose size can change dynamically...
>
> .. Here's the code that creates the text area, makes it the scroll pane's client, and adds the scroll pane to a container.

So you can make your JTextPane the client for your JScrollBar.

### Sample code:

```
public class Sample extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Sample frame = new Sample();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Sample() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(panel);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane
                .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.add(textPane);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textPane);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        insertStringToDoc(getString() + "\n", doc, doc.getLength());

    }

    private void insertStringToDoc(String str, StyledDocument doc, int offset) {
        try {

            SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setForeground(keyWord, Color.RED);
            StyleConstants.setBackground(keyWord, Color.YELLOW);
            StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), str, keyWord);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getString() {
        return "hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
                + "\nhello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
                + "\nhello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
                + "\nhello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
                + "\nhello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
                + "\nhello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
                + "\nhello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
                + "\nhello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
                + "\nhello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
                + "\nhello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
                + "\nhello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
                + "\nhello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
                + "\nhello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
                + "\nhello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello ";
    }
}
```